# How do you disable viewport zooming on Mobile Safari?

Tags: html, ios, zooming, mobile-safari, viewport

I've tried all three of these to no avail:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;” />

<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=false;” />

<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;” />
```

each are different values I found recommended by google searching or SO searching, but none of the '**user-scalable=X**' values seem to be working

I also tried comma delimiting the values instead of semicolon, no luck. Then I tried ONLY having the `user-scalable` value present, still no luck.

---

**UPDATE**

Got this from Apple's site and it works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

it turns out that the problem was the non-standard quotes because I had copied the meta tag from a website that was using them, whoops

Comment: If you're making a game, then possibly controlling zooming is valid. However in nearly all other cases it should be strongly discouraged. Unfortunately it has become standard practice for a lot of mobile developers. If a user wants to zoom in to be able to read text more easily etc. preventing them from doing so isn't very nice.

Comment: We are disabling zoom on a mobile web based application. You can't zoom in Native iOS apps and it's not required in our web application. If your site or app is mobile optimised then your users won't need to zoom. There are always use cases for disabling zoom. It doesn't have to always be one way or the other.

Comment: Pinch to zoom was made popular (not invented) in 2007 when the iPhone was unveiled to solve the problem when mobile websites only offered user-agent adaptive versions of their site or javascript event listener tricks instead of the responsive design versions we take for granted today thanks to CSS3 in 2008. Prior to our mobile HTML 5 rich websites, the internet on a mobile device was considered "the baby web" & everything was tiny to read. Now, when there's an that requires to zoom ANY content or app, they should use the native device zoom here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203332

Comment: Yea I'm not following the line of logic that disabling zoom on a mobile optimised site is a *bad thing*. What's far worse is having the viewport accidentally pan around because the screen is picking up accidental pan and zoom input on a site that doesn't require you to zoom anyway.

Realistically if your users are needing to zoom into content on your mobile optimised site then the problem is the design, not the lack of zoom.

Comment: try shrink-to-fit=no in viewport meta tag

Comment: @NathanHornby: The problem of disabling zoom is a lack of respect of user's preferences. Different users prefers different text sizes, younger audience with good eyesight might prefer to see more content, while audience with poor eyesight can't use anything that doesn't have giant text. Other people have Parkinsons but still have good eyesight, so they prefer extra large buttons but don't benefit from large text in general.

Comment: @Lie Ryan These are very good use-cases, however I feel that they're still mostly accounted for in good design. Global accessibility attributes like text size and *screen* zoom I definitely see as user preference - but the ability to pan/zoom on a webpage isn't an accessibility feature, it's an interface feature. Also keep in mind that the Safari zoom has an upper-limit, and it's not that high - so it doesn't work very well as a 'magnifying glass' for users with sight issues anyway. Accidental pan/zoom is an issue *all* users face, including those with greater accessibility needs.

Comment: @LieRyan mobile first, and accessibility practices.

Comment: @NathanHornby: If your design was so perfect that it suited all users all the time, people wouldn't try to zoom in. If they're trying to zoom in, then they obviously have some reason to do so. Unless you have some specific technical reason to *need to* block pinch zoom, DO NOT BLOCK BLOCK PINCH ZOOM!

Comment: @user1751825 you seem to have missed me using the word 'accidentally'. If your website is designed correctly and mobile optimised, then pinch-zooms are almost definitely *accidental*. By blocking the ability you are preventing user error. If your users need to pinch-zoom on your mobile optimised website then you have done something wrong. This subject is a dead horse.

Comment: @NathanHornby It doesn't mean the designer has done something wrong necessarily. It simply means the user, for whatever reason, wants to zoom in. Pinch-zoom is a standard feature of all touch-screen phones. Any user who owns such a phone, knows how to use it. I know it's an old question, but I still am constantly frustrated by know-all developers who insist on breaking the functionality of my phone because they think it makes their designs look better.

Comment: @user1751825  **It has nothing to do with making anything look better**, as covered it's preventing *undesired behaviour*. I will repeat, a *correctly designed* mobile optimised website has no requirement to be pinch and zoomed. If the issue is a11y then pinch and zoom is a poor solution, it's not how users with sight issues use mobile phones. Literally the only purpose of pinch and zoom in the browser is to enable a user to navigate media and pages that have NOT been optimised for mobile. Turning off features for a purpose not required to avoid unintended behaviour is good design.

Comment: IMO this is an Apple driven propaganda masquerading as an accessibility principle via WCAG. Pinch to zoom is hack to circumvent poor design choices at initial render to begin with.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589861/is-there-a-non-hacky-way-to-prevent-pinch-zoom-on-ios-11-3-safari

Comment: Wow I havent seen this on SO yet - a question based on a typo which should be closed, can have almost 300 upvotes. Because of a typo, lol!

Comment: Browsers are used for more than just regular web pages ie WEB APPS. What about fullscreen drawing-on-a-canvas experiences, with fixed navigation elements? The user expects to have full gesture controls only within the canvas working area. However pinching a fixed header, they do not expect for the entire page container to go flying off in different directions.

Comment: Locking out zoom for users of web pages demonstrates a flagrant disregard for accessibility, regardless of if the content is "mobile optimized." It is impossible to "optimize" any content for all persons, and this is most especially true of those with vision issues. A site (or app for that matter) is not optimized if it does not allow the user to increase the minimum font size (at a minimum). The claim that "accidental panning" is worse is unsupported. There is no "one size fits all" in accessibility, and disabling zoom is a automatic failure.

Answer (score 819, accepted):

Edit: may not work after iOS 10, please see `touch-action` based solution below.

Your code is displaying attribute double quotes as fancy double quotes. If the fancy quotes are present in your actual source code I would guess that is the problem.

This works for me on Mobile Safari in iOS 4.2.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: it was the fancy quotes, I had copied the tag from a website without noticing, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This was great help. I was using "minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" until I realized iOS 6 Safari was allowing pinch zoom on input fields but not on non-input pages. Adding "user-scalable=no" fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps this is at the long tail here but it might be worth pointing out that this needs to be applied at the "top level" page. If you have this meta tag applied to an iframe, it won't work unless the meta tag is also applied to the top-most page.

Comment: Thanks for this. Lots of misinformation out there about this one. Your example works perfectly.

Comment: Why anyone would ever create a piece of software that creates fancy quotes is beyond me.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs: Typography.

Comment: do you also need to use <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>?

Comment: This is a rather old answer and coming to the problem I had read that if you set user-scalable to no this would cause accessibility problems. As of iOS 10 it works fine, allowing the user to zoom if he wishes, but but not zooming the input box otherwise. No need to set large font sizes either.

Comment: @David: If it allows the user to zoom if he wishes, then it doesn't work anymore, does it? After all, the point of user-scalable=no is that it's supposed to *prevent* the user from manually scaling the viewport at all.

Comment: @BoltClock — It doesn't work the way it's intended to, but from my point of view it does exactly what I want. It prevents the automatic zoom when the user clicks in the input, but allows him to zoom himself (and repeatedly). I must admit I was surprised at the result when I added the three scale arguments to the content attribute in the meta tag. I've double-checked it on an iPhone 5 and 6, both running iOS 10.3.3. The pages in question uses an input of type=number, which is not part of a form, for example http://motif.gla.ac.uk/FTB-R/sigfigs.html . I haven't checked an input of type=text yet.

Comment: @BoltClock — I've just seen all the other comments/posts about Apple disabling user-scalable=no, so my initial comment, though meant to be helpful, was old news. Sorry. Clearly if you are in a different situation and have a good reason to want to suppress user pinch-zoom this is a bummer. For me the ability to prevent automatic zoom was all I cared about and is a major HCI improvement.

Comment: @David: Ah, I'm in agreement on that.

Comment: This answer doesn't work on newer iOS versions, as many have noted here in the comments. However, it *is* possible to get this working on newer iOS versions using the `touch-action` CSS property. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62165035

Answer (score 196):

For the people looking for an iOS 10 solution, `user-scaleable=no` is disabled in Safari for iOS 10. The reason is that Apple is trying to improve accessibility by allowing people to zoom on web pages.

**From release notes**:

> To improve accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now
>   pinch-to-zoom even when a website sets user-scalable=no in the
>   viewport.

So as far as I understand, we are sh** out of luck.

Comment: What a terrible decision by Apple.  Using a spinner with "-" and "+" buttons to decrement/increment a number now repeatedly zooms the page in and out on iOS Safari.  The presses are being interpreted as double-tap to zoom, with no way to disable that.  iOS Chrome working perfectly.  Frustrating.

Comment: Although I'm screwed of that decision but I'm really happy from apple as a user as I wanted to force this feature in a lot of websites that were using small elements inside.

Comment: the world is going to hell

Comment: Oh jeez, who would've guessed? Another ridiculous choice made by Apple

Comment: Leave it to Apple to force an accessibility "feature" on everyone instead of just adding an option for it in the **Accessibility** settings...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589861/is-there-a-non-hacky-way-to-prevent-pinch-zoom-on-ios-11-3-safari

Comment: It is possible to get this working on newer iOS versions using the `touch-action` CSS property. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62165035

Comment: Apple hates web apps; they want us all to make native apps for iOS. That's why they keep Safari on the edge of obsolescence but still force everyone to use it. Native apps have no issue here; if you want an element to respond to pinch gestures, you allow them; otherwise you don't. Where's the "accessibility" concern there? It's all baloney.

Comment: Apple is trying to control the websites to increase the App Store profits with new Apps XD

Comment: @EmperorEto We as developers all know that, but how can we convince the rest of the world?

Answer (score 115):

@mattis is correct that iOS 10 Safari won't allow you to disable pinch to zoom with the user-scalable attribute. However, I got it to disable using preventDefault on the 'gesturestart' event. I've only verified this on Safari in iOS 10.0.2.

```
document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nice one, hopefully it's a stable solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me on iOS10, could you provide a running example?

Comment: On iOS 10, I found that this worked, but if you scroll the page and then pinch-zoom while still scrolling, it allows the zoom. Then you find yourself stuck at the new zoom level until you scroll again. So this doesn't look like a good solution unless your page body is not scrollable.  :(

Comment: @RandScullard good catch, not sure how often that happens but it definitely does break this method. I would really only suggest overriding the default if you are providing your own way of zooming the page.

Comment: One caveat: the user can still double tap the screen which will/can zoom and is not caught by this.

Comment: Still sometimes allows zooming by double-tapping the screen. :(

Comment: What is the "double tap" equivalent to `gesturestart`? [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/dblclick)?

Comment: It's worth noting Arthur's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42780478/1283556 addresses the scroll problem, because it allows you to zoom out without having to be scrolling again

Comment: Another note, if you want to disable the double tap aspect of zooming. Mobile Safari also supports 'touch-action: manipulation' (falls under 'basic support', which disables double tap events. Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: I don't know guys but this sounds like a bad idea. I think apple's decision to not disable zoom was for a good reason. It's the same as `outline: none`  Some users will suffer.

Comment: Works with iOS version 11 as well

Comment: This worked for me solving a problem with a pinch zoom image in a website....Thank You

Comment: Works on iOS 15

Answer (score 95):

Using the CSS `touch-action` property is the most elegant solution. Tested on iOS 13.5 and iOS 14.

To disable pinch zoom gestures and and double-tap to zoom:

```css
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

If your app also has no need for **panning**, i.e. scrolling, use this:

```css
body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: the only way I got it working on IOS 13.6.1 thanks!

Comment: This is the current answer.

Comment: NB does not work on iOS 12 and below (which is still quite popular).

Comment: I tried no effect, can still zoom. iPhone6sp IOS 13.6(17G68).

Comment: `touch-action: pan-x pan-y` is unfortunately janky and broken. If you pinch repeatedly it will still zoom about 5% of the time.

Comment: Using `touch-action: pan-x pan-y;` still allows you to zoom while scrolling. If your user zooms unwillingly with that method, he will be stuck zoomed. Not a good idea.

Comment: this works for iOS 13+

Comment: But in double touch the screen change to double size... then user cant return to original scale...

Answer (score 17):

for iphones safari up to iOS 10 "viewport" is not a solution, i don't like this way, but i have used this javascript code and it helped me

```
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent || event;
    if(event.scale > 1) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: It should be `event.scale !== 1`

Comment: @aleclarson event.scale > 1 include condition event.scale !== 1

Comment: @aleclarson for prevent  zooming on Mobile Safari it is enough, i wrote that i don't like this way, normally for it have to be used viewport, but on IOS iphone 6 and higher it is not working (i think your event.scale !== 1 should be more correct, but all this not correct, it is kind of hacking)

Comment: @aleclarson Seems using !== breaks the native browser in Android 4.4; event.scale is undefined.

Comment: @JamesPizzurro Yeah, you can use `event.scale !== undefined && event.scale !== 1`

Comment: iOS 13 change false to {passive: false}

Answer (score 17):

I got it working in iOS 12 with the following code:

```
if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  window.document.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
    if(e.scale !== 1) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }, {passive: false});
}
```

With the first if statement I ensure it will only execute in iOS environments (if it executes in Android the scroll behivour will get broken). Also, note the `passive` option set to `false`.

Comment: Not work on my iOS 12.3.1, here is test link: [https://output.jsbin.com/liqiraj](https://output.jsbin.com/liqiraj)

Comment: This fixed it for me in my Ionic v1 PWA on iOS 14.4!

Comment: This works to prevent page zoom but breaks custom gesture handling.

Answer (score 11):

Actually Apple disabled user-scalable=no on latest iOS versions.
I tried as guideline and this way can work:

```
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

Comment: I tried it on IOS 15, not working!

Answer (score 10):

I managed to stop this behavior by adding the following to the HTML header. This works on mobile devices, as desktop browsers support zooming when using the mouse wheel. It's not a big deal on desktop browsers but it's important to take this into account.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and the following rule to the CSS stylesheet

```css
html {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Comment: "touch-action" do that work - thx

Answer (score 9):

```
user-scalable=0
```

This no longer works on iOS 10. Apple removed the feature.

There is no way yo can disable zoom website on iOS now, unless you make gross platform app.

Comment: Such a bummer... Any idea why they removed this?

Comment: @smt they don't want web experience to compete with app experience on the app store.

Comment: @marvindanig yes... since they take 99$ fee to produce an app that could else easily be made an more accessible web page application for all platform. Also of Apple cannot like a "web experience", if it means users + devs can avoid the walled garden. Its all about power and money of Apple :(

Comment: It is actually possible to get this working on newer iOS versions. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62165035

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the following to your head-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

additionally

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Finally, either as a style-attribute or in your css file, add the following text for webkit-based Browsers:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
}
```

Comment: This answer is outdated. Nonetheless, the meta tag seems to fix a modern bug where many repeated pinch zooms would bypass `touch-action` and even `ongesturestart`. Thank you.

Comment: @BlobKat Then in what way is outdated?

Comment: @HashimAziz meta tag has not worked for nearly a decade.

Comment: HandheldFriendly is for AvantGo browsers which became extinct by 2,009
I had to search for a long time in order to understand why my ex co-worker had added this stupid thing.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine in IOS 10.3.2

```
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        event = event.originalEvent || event;
        if (event.scale !== 1) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
```

thank you @arthur and @aleclarson

Comment: iOS 13 change false to {passive: false}

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned this solution basically works as of late 2020:

```js
document.addEventListener(
    'gesturestart', (e) => e.preventDefault()
);
```

But the downside is that while you are scrolling you'd still be able to pinch and then it gets stuck.
The solution is to disable scrolling.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But, what if you still wanted the page to be scrolled?
You can still do it with another `<div>` set as `overflow:auto`:

```html
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>
</div>
```

and then

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

 #app {
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      height: 100vh;
      height: -webkit-fill-available;
      overflow: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

sometimes those other directives in the `content` tag can mess up Apple's best guess/heuristic at how to layout your page, all you need to disable pinch zoom is.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In Safari 9.0 and up you can use **shrink-to-fit** in viewport meta tag as shown below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Answer (score 2):

**2023 Update: on accessibility and the current state of Safari IOS**

We had an auto-zoom issue with an input focus in a form, in Safari iOS. Solving the issue turned out to be more complex that we expected.

Quoting @haltersweb below:

> "In order to comply with WAI WCAG 2.0 AA accessibility requirements you must never disable pinch zoom. (WCAG 2.0: SC 1.4.4 Resize text Level AA"

If the accessibility requirements don't sway you, the **9 point penalty incurred in Google Lighthouse** for accessibility requirements violations — with the corresponding SEO downgrade – will give you some pause. Yes, Chrome Mobile is affected. Do not disable pinch zoom.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this issue that we tested and work (kudos to [Rick Strahl for his research and blogpost](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2023/Apr/17/Preventing-iOS-Safari-Textbox-Zooming)):

- Make sure that your input fields have `font-size: 16px` or greater.
- Use `maximum-scale=1` in the viewport meta tag selectively for iOS Safari.

Although the second solution sounds promising and we didn't want to deal with changing the design of the inputs, getting the font-size to 16px is the appropriate way to deal with this. It is always better to abstain from introducing hacks that in the end, you'll have to maintain for many years, and that will come with unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all above things but this worked for me on IOS devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Oct. 2022) with iOS 14.8, the ONLY way I could completely prevent the double tap zoom was this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        })
```

Even this:

```
* {
    touch-action: none !important;
}
```

(which is obviously not realistic, but just for demonstration purposes) wasn't enough in every case. It turned out that any for element on which I had handled `click`, double tapping on it would cause a nearly irreversible zoom-in, completely ignoring the `touch-action` setting. But if I called `preventDefault()` in the click handler, it would not zoom. So, doing this at the `document` level so far seems to be enough, so that I don't have to do it every time I handle `click`.

I have no idea what side effects this might have, but I'm sure folks will chime in if they think of any.

Comment: Doesn't this disable clicking any links?

Comment: @HashimAziz I believe that's right yes. This is really only appropriate for SPAs with totally custom controls. But of course that's probably the only scenario where it's appropriate to disable iOS's zoom. Anyway, I do not deny this is by no means ideal and if anyone knows a better way to do this and have it work on newer iOS I'd be happy to use it!

Answer (score -1):

I foolishly had a wrapper div which had a width measured in pixels.  The other browsers seemed to be intelligent enough to deal with this.  Once I had converted the width to a percentage value, it worked fine on Safari mobile as well. Very annoying.

```
.page{width: 960px;}
```

to

```
.page{width:93.75%}

<div id="divPage" class="page">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to comply with WAI WCAG 2.0 AA accessibility requirements you must **never disable** pinch zoom.  (WCAG 2.0: SC 1.4.4 Resize text Level AA).  You can read more about it here:  [Mobile Accessibility: How WCAG 2.0 and Other W3C/WAI Guidelines Apply to Mobile, 2.2 Zoom/Magnification](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/#zoom-magnification)

Comment: This is not an answer.. and many clients yet ask to block zoom.. so I can't take this as a general rule

Comment: Accessibility zoom is not the page's (neither any app for that matter) responsibility. It is the operating system's responsibility to provide an accessible zooming tool. Every OS nowadays provides such feature, which applies as a *screen zoom*, and it should not interfere with the page's zooming itself, because this is not intended for accessibility.

Comment: I disagree with the comments above. I think disabling pinch-zoom in iOS and Android is a clear fail criterion for 1.4.4 for WCAG Level AA. But like a lot of things with WCAG, it is debatable.

Comment: There are always valid use cases for stuff like this. For some reason, pretty much all web literature seems to assume that the web is only for making blogs. Just as there are valid use cases for JavaScript's `eval()`, so are there for disabling zooming. I am using it for a web-app that is used in combination with a Bluetooth scanner, to prevent the page zooming when a barcode is scanned.

Comment: I completely agree with the aims of the accessibility recommendations, but there's no question that there are times when zoom is not desired or needed, or may even break the user experience. Plus, you know, clients.

Comment: I'd say that in a html/javascript app, those guidelines do not apply. After all, would a native app let you zoom in and out?

Comment: You raise an interesting point Jorgen.  It all depends on whether or not the HTML site in question is required to follow the W3C's WCAG 2.0 AA rating.  Here is an interesting read by the W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/#zoom-magnification.  It raises a distinction between OS-level features and browser-level features.  It also talks about how other methods besides zoom can be utilized as long as the following criterion is met:  "text must be resizable without assistive technology up to 200 percent."

Comment: There are always cases where disabling the zoom makes perfect sense. 

In a web app brought up by a native app for example, you wouldn't want your customers to be able to zoom.

Comment: I've just built an image zoomer on a page that contains no text; overriding the default zoom to provide enhanced zoom functionality seems like a perfectly good time to disable the browser's pinch zoom.

Comment: This is not an answer. Furthermore one may disable native zoom and reimplement it programmatically preserving or even improving accessibiIity

Comment: The workarounds, solve half the issue, but still aren't 100% indestructible,  imo it would make sense to have a browser option like to "disable javascript" if said people choose to do so. clients!

Answer (score -4):

This one should be working on iphone etc.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```