# Disabling mobile Safari's focus event (zoom)

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

When clicking an input field on an iOS device, it will zoom in on that element. Can i disable this focus event?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put up this gist which solves the problem.
https://gist.github.com/2008932

The accepted solution is not correct, as it will cancel focus altogether, which prevents data entry.

Comment: Excellent! Can't believe everyone is still advising viewport hacks when this seems to solve this issue quite elegantly. Thanks

Comment: For the record, this is a viewport hack—it’s just dynamic in JavaScript. :)

Comment: If you are using mobile boilerplate (http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/) with helper.js you can call MBP.preventZoom(), its does pretty much the same work

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. All others were giving foul behavior or messing with the viewPort to the point where responsiveness would be overwritten. Thanks Zach!

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better to set the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: I disagree. With @zachleat's solution it is not needed to completely disable zooming. Disabling zooming alltogether in most cases is a bad idea: you're disabling a standard interaction.

Comment: Not only is this user hostile it also doesn’t work (thankfully) in iOS10+.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("idOfInputField").onfocus = function(){return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to disable auto zoom in mobile devices on touch event

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">`