# Disable iOS zoom for text inputs?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, meta-tags

I'm working on an iOS web app and I have the viewport set to not scalable via...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
```

The problem is that when I focus on an input text field, it zooms in and doesn't zoom out:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Full size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N50Vg.png

Comment: Looks like this might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002854/disabling-mobile-safaris-focus-event-zoom

Comment: The solution there does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this tag,

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

It's been really buggy in iOS5, and after removing it from the `div`, the zoom problem did not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; intial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
```

This prevents it from scaling.

Comment: I have this same tag in my OP.