# Bootstrap 3: horizontal scrollbar on iPhone after form focus

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, there seems to have been an issue with the [fluid grid causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear on small devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392477/how-to-make-bootstrap-3-fluid-layout-without-horizontal-scrollbar). My question is different...

I'm not getting any scrollbar, unless I click a text input. On an iPhone, there is an automatic zoom on the current field. This is ok (I guess), but after leaving the field, the zoom is not removed, so the content is clipped and there's an ugly horizontal scrollbar.

Is there a way to prevent the zoom? Or maybe tell mobile safari to set the zoom back to what it was?

Comment: Use search:

[Disabling mobile Safari's focus event (zoom)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002854/disabling-mobile-safaris-focus-event-zoom),


[Disable Auto Zoom in Input “Text” tag - Safari on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone)

Answer (score 9):

First: you can create fluid-responsive tables. But you do not need it. If you don't give the `<table>` the `class="responsive"` the horizontal scroolbar doesn´t appear.

If you want to disable the zoom on small devices use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: That meta viewport setting should be default on all mobile devices -_-