# Double tap on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

Is there a way to bind to a double-tap event (in a single line of code) for mobile safari? Or, the alternative is to implement it intercepting two single-tap events that happened in some short given time (example: http://appcropolis.com/blog/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/)?

Comment: Is the double tab not used for zoom? Is 2 tap events even fired in the browser?

Comment: same event that is used for zoom and I'd like to override the behavior for a concrete given situation

Comment: Sorry if i'm not relating to your problem but if your displaying a webpage you can specify the viewport setting's in the meta tag. You can see this in the iwebkit from snippetspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** you must implement via two clicks.

**Actual answer:** Here is a jQuery-free implementation of double-tap for mobile safari which only requires one line of code (to enable dblclick event):

- https://gist.github.com/2927073

In addition, you will likely need to [disable mobile Safari's default zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari) with this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: posting a link to an offsite code is not an acceptable answer

Comment: It was a fine answer in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have working double click both on browser and IOS platform, you should have the following code:

```
jQuery.event.special.dblclick = {
    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (agent.indexOf('iphone') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipad') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipod') >= 0) {
            var elem = this,
                $elem = jQuery(elem);
            $elem.bind('touchend.dblclick', jQuery.event.special.dblclick.handler);
        } else {
            var elem = this,
                $elem = jQuery(elem);
            $elem.bind('click.dblclick', jQuery.event.special.dblclick.handler);
        }
    },
    teardown: function(namespaces) {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (agent.indexOf('iphone') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipad') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipod') >= 0) {
            var elem = this,
                $elem = jQuery(elem);
            $elem.unbind('touchend.dblclick');
        } else {
            var elem = this,
                $elem = jQuery(elem);
            $elem.unbind('click.dblclick', jQuery.event.special.dblclick.handler);
        }
    },
    handler: function(event) {
        var elem = event.target,
            $elem = jQuery(elem),
            lastTouch = $elem.data('lastTouch') || 0,
            now = new Date().getTime();
        var delta = now - lastTouch;
        if (delta > 20 && delta < 500) {
            $elem.data('lastTouch', 0);
            $elem.trigger('dblclick');
        } else {
            $elem.data('lastTouch', now);
        }
    }
};
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UXRF8/

Answer (score 0):

Override `dblclick` event and use `bind`, `live`, `on`, `delegate` like for any other event:

```
jQuery.event.special.dblclick = {
    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
        var elem = this,
            $elem = jQuery(elem);
        $elem.bind('touchend.dblclick', jQuery.event.special.dblclick.handler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
        var elem = this,
            $elem = jQuery(elem);
        $elem.unbind('touchend.dblclick');
    },

    handler: function(event) {
        var elem = event.target,
            $elem = jQuery(elem),
            lastTouch = $elem.data('lastTouch') || 0,
            now = new Date().getTime();

        var delta = now - lastTouch;
        if(delta > 20 && delta<500){
            $elem.data('lastTouch', 0);
            $elem.trigger('dblclick');
        }else
            $elem.data('lastTouch', now);
    }
};
```