# iOS Safari Double Tap Button Issue

Tags: javascript, ios, css, meteor, mobile-safari

I'm creating a mobile app with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com) and I'm having problems with buttons in the Safari Webview. It seems like at totally random times and buttons, I'm forced to tap on something twice in order for the click to register. I have research a lot about the problems and all the answers have not worked for me.

Almost all the buttons/links in my app use javascript for their function. I don't use any `:hover` in my CSS.

I can't find any pattern or reason for when it happens. It seems totally random. It makes my app feel unresponsive and slow because you have to tap half of the stuff twice for it to register. I doesn't seem to happen when I'm using the app in a desktop browser.

Has anyone ran into this problem before or know of solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11024683/4831524

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double tap on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278147/double-tap-on-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of tapping, are your buttons in the bottom 44px of the viewport? It could be caused by [Safari's hostile menu bar](https://benfrain.com/the-ios-safari-menu-bar-is-hostile-to-web-apps-discuss/).

If so the only solution I can think of is to move those links outside of that area. If anyone has a better solution, I'd be interested myself as well. (None of the solutions I've found have worked so far, including styles on the content;

```
.parent {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

or adding some padding to the bottom positioned element;

```
.bottom-positioned-element {
   padding-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with a link on my page so I applied this SCSS / CSS solution.  Is it possible with your setup that a hover is being added elsewhere to some of the links..? even though there is no style change..?

https://gist.github.com/PocketNinjaDesign/689e16e412a88dfd36dd08b26bebcacf

```
a.close {
  background: #fc0;

  @media (hover: hover) {
    &:hover {
      background: #f00;
    }
  }
}
```

as specified in the mozzilla docs ;-)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

Answer (score 0):

I had this double-tap issue caused by lightSlider due to its use of touchstart and touchmove that somehow triggered the bug in iOS. Like in your case there was no hover effects that could possibly be the culprit. After thorough investigation I could resolve my issue with this piece of script (added to the beginning of body):

```
<script type="module">document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){});</script>
```

I couldn't really tell why it worked but it seemed like adding touchstart/touchmove listeners and removing them (possibly in certain circumstances) caused the issue - like it somehow didn't remove the listener and it somehow prevented click events from occuring.

Somebody should report this bug to webkit. I couldn't find any existing report.