# impossible to use dblclick() function in safari iphone?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios

I make my first mobile web app, but one fonctionnality doesn't work on iphone:
the dblclick() function.

Actually, I want to add a `ìmg` in favorite when I double click on the picture, but when i double click in the `ìmg` on Iphone, there is a zoom on the picture.

```php
echo '<div class="section">
    <img id="'.$row['id'].'" class="anim photo" data-delay=".2s" src="'.$row['url'].'">
    <p class="anim_commentaire commentaire ';
     if (in_array($row['id'],$list)) {
         echo "commentaire_like";
     }
    echo '" data-delay=".3s">'.$row['description'].'</p>
</div>';
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").dblclick(function(){        
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var method = "GET";
                var url = "like.php?id_photo="+$(this).attr("id");
                var asynchronous = true;
                ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
                ajax.send();
                if($(this).siblings().hasClass('commentaire_like')){
                    $(this).siblings().removeClass("commentaire_like");
                }else{
                    $(this).siblings().addClass("commentaire_like");
                }

    });
});
```

I already try the solutions of other posts but nothing has unlocked me, including `<meta />`or https://jsfiddle.net/UXRF8/ this for example

This is working on android Phone and on windows computer.
Someone know if it's possible to make this possible for IOS?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this bad UX? Why would you want to implement the dblClick functionality...

Comment: I want to make something when user doubleclick on my img. There's others solution for IOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double tap on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278147/double-tap-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: I already try the solutions of other posts but nothing has unlocked me