# Prevent re-size on zoom using bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to the CSS/HTML world. I am creating an interactive image using html hotspots, CSS and bootstrap to create modal information about certain parts of the image. The image is very wide (its a process road map) and will be used on a large touch screen for a presentation only. The issue I am having is that when the bootstrap modal is opened it appears at the zoom level of the browser. Since this is a very large image and the user can zoom in and out I need to make the data on the modal appear static in size/zoom. I have used viewpoints to keep the size of the text static and this works well for 100+ - 60% zoom. What does not work well is when I zoom far out the text overlaps itself, 50% or less which is possible if people want to see the whole image before clicking the link to open the modal. The layout on the modal is two rows of three columns using bootstrap. The columns do not overlap its that the text wraps over itself. I'm not sure how to fix this problem or perhaps another approach is better all together.

I have played with changing the size of the image which helps some, but at some point varying zooms will be used no matter what image size I use thus the problem occurs.

What it is doing at 45% zoom, text size is OK but its overlapping:
[image: What its doing 45% zoom]

What I need it to look like at any zoom:
[image: What I need it to look like at any zoom]

CSS for modal content: 
    /**** Start details Model Content Section ****/

```
.details, .details-2 {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.details {
    text-align: center;
     min-height: 100px;
}
.details h4{
    font-size: 2.5vmin;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.details-2 h4{
    font-size: 2.5vmin;
    color: #444;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.details p, .details-2 p {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 2vmin;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}


.details i {
   font-size:3.5em;
   color:#fff;
    background: #FF432E;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
   padding:25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius:70%;
   -moz-border-radius:70%;
   -o-border-radius:70%;
   border-radius:70%;
   position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(2, 2, 2);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(2, 2, 2);
    -o-transform: translate3d(2, 2, 2);
    transform: translate3d(2, 2, 2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
}
.no-touch .details:hover i,
    .no-touch .details:active i,
    .no-touch .details:focus i {

        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #FF432E;
}


.details-2 i {
    color:#FF432E;
   font-size:3em;
   padding:1px 10px 0 1px;
   position: relative;

}

.container {
    width: 96%;
    height: 96%; 
}



/**** End details Modal Content Section ****/
```

Comment: Can you please create a working fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried the *viewport* meta tag? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari/4389976#4389976)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hope62/5c7f4rq1/      I removed the image map as the image I am using cannot be posted.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` should help on mobile scaling problems.

Place between the `<head>` and `</head>`

Comment: This will prevent all zoom action, right? I'm not sure that's what the OP is after.

Comment: I can't have zoom eliminated all together as the main image the modal is triggered from requires zooming. Perhaps using a new page in the modal with the zoom disabled may work though?

Comment: @isherwood - this meta tag only prevents zooming when it has the `user-scalable` attribute set to `false`

Comment: Fair enough. Please describe in your answer how exactly it "helps".