# Site zooms out when menu is opened

Tags: mobile-safari, yui-pure-css

I'm using Yahoo's PureCSS library along with a plugin for the sidebar and it works great on all browsers except mobile Safari. For some reason, it zooms out whenever the menu is opened. This even occurs in the documentation's [example](http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/). I have no idea what could be causing this but it's tempting to just call it a browser bug.

I can put together a JSFiddle if necessary.

Comment: You should definitely add a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question actually boiled down to being the same as [Does overflow:hidden applied to  work on iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari). I guess Mobile Safari will zoom out to make room for the menu and the content area when the user opens the menu, unless you do this on a wrapper element:

```
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The viewport meta tag does not contain a maximum scale value. If you update the viewport tag to the following, you won't get the same zooming whenever the user clicks on the menu:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Note the addition of `maximum-scale=1` to the end of the string. When this is added, the content slides over instead of zooming out. This was tested against the [PureCSS](http://purecss.io/) demo page for the [Responsive Side Menu](http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/), linked to above.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not having any luck with that or any of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari)