# Can't block scaling for mobile devices iOS10

Tags: html

I am newbie in front end and maybe it is a stupid question.

**I have added**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

but it wouldn't help. Any ideas how to fix it.

hear is the page which I am talking about.
https://github.com/AlexK89/Portfolio-page

**UPDATE:**
Just this script solved my problem.

`document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {if (event.touches.length > 1) { event.preventDefault();}}, false);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable viewport zooming on Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: This is apparently disabled by Apple as of iOS 10. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39711930/1161948) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38852262/1161948) for more info.