# Disable Zoom on mobile devices

Tags: java, html, iphone, mobile, viewport

I was following this guide to disable zoom for mobile devices.

https://davidwalsh.name/zoom-mobile-browsers

As many others have suggested the guide suggests using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
```

I've tried this and several variations with the viewport and I cannot get it to work. Also when looking at the example from the guide I followed I realized it also doesn't work.

https://davidwalsh.name/demo/mobile-viewport.php

Any thoughts on why this is not working and any suggestions on how to make it work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is ok, the problem is iOS specific. Quoted from another question here on stackoverflow:

> For the people looking for an iOS 10 solution, user-scaleable=no is
>   disabled in Safari for iOS 10. The reason is that Apple is trying to
>   improve accessibility by allowing people to zoom on web pages.

See the whole thread here:
[How do you disable viewport zooming on Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari)

Or this one:
[disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

Comment: Than maybe some of your html element is wider than 100%. Try to fix it by commenting out (temporarily remove) all your html inside the `<body></body>` tag and then put it back one by one. Or at first try with a really simple body content like `<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>` and try zooming. If it's ok (cannot be zoomed) with minimal body content then the bug is somewhere in your html code.

Comment: Also disable any css when testing the above. Maybe a css rule is messing with the html or the body tag.

Comment: hmm I'll give it a shot! I am curious why the example I was using also wasn't working. Check the link above on mobile

Comment: For me the demo link works on Android as it should be: no zooming allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple application.
I chance style with `max-zoom: 3;`

Note; `max-zoom: 3` code run for disable double click.
This note is true even if `min-zoom: 3` is added.