# Is there a non-hacky way to prevent pinch zoom on iOS 11.3 Safari?

Tags: ios, web, accessibility

I *really* want to disable pinch to zoom on my webpages (iframes) and use finger pinching events for another custom interaction. So while Apple in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) says that it supports the following clause:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

…in practice their Safari browser on iOS and iPadOS does not honor it.

The ability to prevent viewport zooming is generally important for the experience of gaming on the web and for tight user experience near buttons, input boxes and slide-in/slide-out type of interfaces (think Tinder). Even on videos pinch-zooming is not required, but maybe `pinchzoom` can remain a good default on ereaders?

It is worth mentioning here that there is a stripped down `reader` mode on iOS Safari too, that provides for uncluttered reading with desired accessibility features.

IMHO, applying accessibility guideline aimed at low vision readers on every other use-case on the web is super draconian. While it is possible to disable `pinchzoom` using a `passive` event listener, but for the sake of hygiene, the question is: Is there a non-hacky way of doing it?

---

In a [recent discussion](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/602#issuecomment-390490730) with W3C/WCAG team it was clarified (emphasis mine) that the accessibility guidelines specify only…

> a SHOULD NOT author conformance requirement that has been in the spec
>   since 2016 arronei/html@877b59c. It is an author conformance
>   requirement only, that **does not forbid the use** but does ask authors to
>   consider seriously the curtailment of user's ability to zoom. What
>   apple have done in safari is beyond the scope of this issue as it does
>   not require anything of browser implementers.

With the recent changes on iOS Safari, Apple appears to have bent the accessibility guidelines towards a `CANNOT` author conformance for reasons best (;-)) known to them. It is important that this difference between the spec and implementation be highlighted here for the record.

---

Following discussions with the Apple iOS Safari team a bug was filed with webkit for this conformance issue [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186970).

Comment: Since iPadOS 16 (maybe sooner), a working solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492869/418974

Comment: The issue is that the vast majority of cases where pinch-to-zoom is disabled is websites written by people who don't know anything about UX.  Overriding that and enabling pinch-to-zoom improves those sites.  If the web weren't littered with such poorly-implemented sites, pinch-to-zoom wouldn't have to be forced on the infinitesimal minority of web apps (almost all videogames) where it should be disabled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `touch-action: none` on the `html, body` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#none

https://github.com/msand/InfiniDraw/commit/b96aac5f8313f56da7be6f9e9f24648ab02fc444

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari on iPadOS 16. Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525704/disable-pinch-zoom-on-ios-13-safari

Comment: The document doubles its size when double touched ...

Comment: That's because Apple will try every trick in their book to keep the web experience inferior in comparison to the app stores. It's been _known_ for a while.

Answer (score 3):

While there isn't a non-hacky way to prevent `pinchzoom`, there is a hack that works on iOS 11.3 Safari still. At least for now. See [inobounce](https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce) that handles both rubber band behavior and pinchzoom in one fell sweep.

Comment: The specific fix that inobounce uses is to pass `{ passive: false }` as the `options` parameter of the `addEventListener` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners

Comment: inobounce does not prevent pinch to zoom when I open examples on the iOS 13