# Cross platform disable zoom in functionality in android and IOS both

Tags: html, css, angular5

I am trying to disable zoom in functionality in android and IOS for a mobile friendly website. I have tried these solutions but its working for android and iPhone 5 but not for iPhone 5+ and iPad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a non-hacky way to prevent pinch zoom on iOS 11.3 Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589861/is-there-a-non-hacky-way-to-prevent-pinch-zoom-on-ios-11-3-safari)

Comment: In iOS / Safari, Apple does not respect disabled zoom on websites per intent - this has started in iOS 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Zooming is handled by the scaleble attribute in viewport (you can also configure what is the default scale)

```
    <meta name='viewport', content='width=device-width, 
     initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

Keep in mind, this disable scaling in general. If you want to limit it to mobile screens only, you need to use a specific `@media` query (depending on which size you want and what kind of devices you want to limit)

Comment: I want to disable it for all the devices (android and ios),but as I mentioned it's working for android and iPhone 5 only

Comment: Provide us with a code you're using. But either way, the one I provided should work.

Comment: I am using the same which you have suggested