# HTML5 Mobile Page - Disable Zooming

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am working on a HTML5 mobile application and we want to disable zooming on all pages.

Adding this meta tag seem to work except users can scroll + zoom which we don't want.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

How can I disable it completely?

BTW, I have added this to CSS also.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
touch-action: none;
```

Comment: Do the most recent answers on this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari/62165035#62165035 help?

Comment: Please take into account that you are hurting the accessibility of your application with disabling the zooming functionality. Your also taking away the chance for custom preferences of your user's.